# Having problems with Kafka AdminClient trying to get the lag of a consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have been trying to to use AdminClient to get the lag of a consumer but adminClient.listGroupOffsets("foo"); returns a null pointer NullPointerException.
 Here is my code:

```
public long getLag() {
    AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.createSimplePlaintext("localhost:9092");
    scala.collection.immutable.Map<TopicPartition, Object> offsets = adminClient.listGroupOffsets("foo");
    Option<Object> offset = offsets.get(new TopicPartition("test", 0));
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("test", 0);
    return getLogEndOffset(topicPartition)- Long.parseLong(offset.get().toString());

}

private long getLogEndOffset(TopicPartition tp) {
    KafkaConsumer consumer = createNewConsumer();
    Collections.singletonList(tp);
    consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(tp));
    consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(tp));
    return consumer.position(tp);
}

private KafkaConsumer createNewConsumer() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "g1");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    return new KafkaConsumer(properties);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listGroupOffsets` api is introduced in 2.12. Possible cause is version mismatch with broker version.

The broker only supports `OffsetFetchRequest` v1, but you need v2 or newer to request all topic partitions.

Comment: 2.12? Which version is this referring to? Did you mean 0.10.2?